# Get a window by coordinates

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a point in screen coordinates and I need to find which window it "falls" onto. I.e. find the window (hWND) that is foremost of all windows containing the point. Pinvoke and WinApi is fine...

PS. I actually need to detect, which window is my mouse cursor currently "over", to put it another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! How could I overlook that